# Overlays -- how to prevent bold faces from trumping non-bold faces

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm looking for some assistance, please, to control **bold** faces in conjunction with overlays.  With the standard `font-lock` method, it is generally sufficient to place `:bold nil` in the other face to prevent it from being trumped.  However, that same concept doesn't seem to apply when dealing with overlays.  When dealing with overlays, what else can be done to prevent **bold** from bleeding through to other faces?

For example:  when two overlays overlap, how can I prevent `tab-face` **bold** from trumping `hr-underscore-face`?

```lisp
(defface tab-face
  '((t (:foreground "cyan" :bold t)))
  "Face for `tab-face`."
  :group 'lawlist-ruler-faces)

(defface hr-underscore-face
  '((t (:underline "yellow" :bold nil)))
  "Face for `hr-underscore-face`."
  :group 'lawlist-ruler-faces)
```

---

**EDIT** (June 19, 2014):  Added sample `.emacs` configuration to reproduce issue, and two screenshots.  The path to the `ispell-program-name` would need to be set according to the user's own setup.

```lisp
;; GNU Emacs 24.4.50.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0,
;; NS appkit-1038.36 Version 10.6.8 (Build 10K549)) of 2014-06-01 on MP.local

(set-face-attribute 'default nil
  :background "black" :foreground "white" :font "Courier" :height 180)

(tool-bar-mode -1)

(require 'ispell)

(require 'flyspell)

(setq-default ispell-program-name
    "/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/elpa/bin/aspell")

(custom-set-faces
  '(flyspell-incorrect ((t (:foreground "yellow" :weight bold ))))
  '(highlight ((t (:underline "yellow" :weight normal)))))

(defun zoom ()
(interactive)
  (setq buffer-face-mode-face `(:height 575))
  (buffer-face-mode 1))

(defun test-number-one ()
(interactive)
  (switch-to-buffer (get-buffer-create "test-number-ONE"))
  (zoom)
  (turn-on-flyspell)
  (setq flyspell-mark-duplications-flag nil)
  (setq flyspell-duplicate-distance 0)
  (hl-line-mode 1)
  (insert
    "This is `test-number-one`."
    "\n"
    "\n"
    "Aabbccddeeffgghhiijjkkllmmnnooppqqrrssttuuvvwwxxyyzz"
    "\n"
    "\n"
    "Aabbccddeeffgghhiijjkkllmmnnooppqqrrssttuuvvwwxxyyzz"))


(defun test-number-two ()
(interactive)
  (switch-to-buffer (get-buffer-create "test-number-TWO"))
  (zoom)
  (hl-line-mode 1)
  (insert
    "This is `test-number-two`."
    "\n"
    "\n"
    "Aabbccddeeffgghhiijjkkllmmnnooppqqrrssttuuvvwwxxyyzz"
    "\n"
    "\n"
    "Aabbccddeeffgghhiijjkkllmmnnooppqqrrssttuuvvwwxxyyzz"))
```

---

In example number one, the underline is **bold**.  [However, I'd like to learn how to make the underline consistently have a *normal* weight (even though the `:foreground` of the text is **bold**).]

[image: Example]
<sub>(source: [lawlist.com](http://www.lawlist.com/images/example_06_19_2014_a.png))</sub>

---

In example number two, the underline is *normal*.

[image: Example]
<sub>(source: [lawlist.com](http://www.lawlist.com/images/example_06_19_2014_b.png))</sub>

Answer (score 2):

`:bold` is a compatibility alias.  For finer control, use `:weight`, e.g.

```
(defface hr-underscore-face
  '((t (:underline "yellow" :weight normal)))
  "Face for `hr-underscore-face`."
  :group 'lawlist-ruler-faces)
```

Comment: Thank you -- I'll keep working on this project over the next few days and see if I can put together a short working example to reproduce what I'm seeing.  It appears that using an overlay containing just an underline (e.g., `(:underline "yellow" :weight normal)`) at the same location as another overlay with **bold** (e.g., `(:foreground "cyan" :weight bold)` leads to a situation that confuses Emacs, and it matters as to which overlay was first placed.  I'm seeing this with `flyspell-incorrect`; and, also a `buffer-display-table` modification where I have a **bold** glyph coloring for tabs.

Comment: Essentially, I'd like to use overlays to underline an entire horizontal line of text (which text may or may not contain some **bold**); and, I'd like the underline to have a *normal* weight for the entire length of the horizontal line (*without* changing the appearance of the **bold** text that may be present above the underline).  It is very similar to `hl-line-mode`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the problem you report, even with the code you posted (though I agree with @Stefan about `:weight normal`).

Evaluating your code I get this, which shows the yellow underline throughout the buffer and bold text only on a piece of the last line:

[image]

What am I missing?  (This is with the buffer in Text mode and `font-lock-mode` turned off.)

Comment: Thank you for taking a look at this thread -- much appreciated!  I've updated the question with sample code to reproduce the issue I'm seeing, and two screenshots.  If possible, I'd like to learn of a way to consistently control having overlays at the same position with the `:foreground` being *bold* and the `:underline` being *normal*.  Flyspell uses overlays, instead of `font-lock`, so that is why I chose that example.  `hl-line-mode` also uses overlays, instead of `font-lock`.  The situation is likely somewhat special when dealing with two competing overlays at the same position.

Comment: The minor-mode that I've been writing / toiling with is a suped-up version of `vline-mode` and `hl-line-mode`.  Resolving this particular issue that can be seen in `hl-line-mode` will likewise resolve the same issue I see with my custom cross-hairs mode.

Comment: Try using a higher `priority` value for the overlay that uses the nderline face.  Overlay priorities usually let you move one overlay on top of another (visually).  (And you should try to give minimal code if you want people to try to repro something.  You should be able to repro your problem without bringing in various modes etc.)

Comment: Thank you for the `priority` suggestion.  This is going to be a work in progress thread.  I've made some headway tonight by identifying that my cursor overlay has a significant impact on the visual issue described in this thread -- I have four (4) *base* groups of overlays happening here -- (1) from the left widow edge to the cursor (underlined); (2) cursor (bold, but not underlined); (3) after the cursor to the end of line (underlined); and, (4) an after-string (underline) from end of line to the right window edge.  Flyspell is a fifth (5th) element coming on the scene. . . .

Comment: See also [Emacs bug #17824](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=17824). It might be relevant; dunno.

Comment: Sorry; didn't recognize you. ;-)